# How to make two unequal 2D arrays equal by adding zeroes in null positions in java?

Tags: java, arrays

lets say my matrix A has order of 3 x 2 and Matrix B has order of 2 x 4. My resultant Matrix should be in the order of 3 x 4 and it should contain the addition of Matrix A and Matrix B. In order to achieve this I must first make Matrix A and Matrix B equal in size (both should be 3 x 4) by appending the necessary zeroes.

EXAMPLE :-

```
int[][] a = { {1,0}, {1,1}, {1,0} }; 
int[][] b = { {1,1,0,1}, {1,1,1,1} };
```

sumArray(a,b) will return: { {2,1,0,1}, {2,2,1,1}, {1,0,0,0} }

what I tried was. (ans.length means the resultant matrix length)

```
for(int i =0;i<ans.length;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<ans[i].length;j++)
    {
     if(arr1[i][j] == null)
     {
       arr1[i][j]= 0;
     }
      if(arr2[i][j] == null)
     {
       arr2[i][j]= 0;
     }
    }
  }
```

Comment: what is your problem??

Comment: How do you define your matrixes?

Comment: Show how the matrices are defined.

Comment: @matt by using 2D arrays

Comment: may sound stupid, but use primitive arrays? they are zeroed by default

Comment: @Gimhani 

int[][] a = {
    {1,0},
    {1,1},
    {1,0}
};
int[][] b = {
    {1,1,0,1},
    {1,1,1,1}
};

sumArray(a,b) will return:

{
    {2,1,0,1},
    {2,2,1,1},
    {1,0,0,0}
}

Comment: can you please update the question with this. @ObitoUchiha

Comment: @Gimhani done...

Comment: You cannot append to an array, You'll have to create new ones. Your tests for null will not work. You'll probably get index out of bounds exceptions.

Comment: @matt Yes thats exactly what i got. then how can i make two unequal 2D arrays to same size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to find the size of your output array.

```
int h = a.length>b.length?a.length:b.length;
int w = a[0].length>b[0].length?a[0].length:b[0].length;
int[][] result = new int[h][w];
```

Then do your assignments.

```
for(int i = 0; i<result.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<result[i].length; j++){
        if(i<a.length && j < a[i].length){
            result[i][j] += a[i][j];
        }
        if(i<b.length && j < b[i].length){
            result[i][j] += b[i][j];
        }

    }
}
return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. Just make the dimension identifying part dynamic

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Main
{

  public static void main (String[]args)
  {
    System.out.println ("Hello World");
    int m1 = 3, n1 = 1, m2 = 2, n2 = 4; // m1 and n1 are matrix 'x' dimensions and m2 & n2 are natrix 'y' dimensions
    int x[][] = {
      {1},
      {2},
      {3}
    };
    int y[][] = {
      {1, 2, 1, 2},
      {1, 2, 1, 2}};

     int op[][] = new int[m1][n2];
     for (int[] row: op)// filling empty matrix with zeroes
     Arrays.fill(row, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < m1; i++)
      {
    for (int j = 0; j < n1; j++)
      {
        op[i][j] = x[i][j];
      }
      }
    int op2[][] = new int[m1][n2];
    for (int[] row: op2)// filling empty matrix with zeroes
     Arrays.fill(row, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < m2; i++)
      {
    for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++)
      {
        op2[i][j] = y[i][j];
      }
      }

      for(int i=0;i<m1; i++)
      {
          for(int j=0;j<n2;j++)
          {
              System.out.print((op[i][j]+op2[i][j])+" ");
          }
          System.out.println();
      }

  }
}
```

Comment: int[]'s are filled with zero automatically.